# Understanding the getParent method for a Java applet

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

I'm trying out a tutorial that uses a class which inherits from the Applet class. I'm having difficulty grasping the concept of the line which creates a frame object. I'm not sure what the 2 getParent() calls do.

Does the first getParent() call reference the StartingClass's parent which is Applet?
Does the second getParent() call reference the Applet's parent which is Panel?

I seriously believe I'm looking at it wrong and am looking for clarification.

```
public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Q-Bot Alpha");
    }
```

Comment: *"I seriously believe I'm looking at it wrong"*  What you're looking at is fragile code that should not be used for study.  1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `getParent` will return `sun.applet.AppletViewerPanel` and second will return `sun.applet.AppletViewer`.

Here is the declaration of `AppletViewer` class

```
public class sun.applet.AppletViewer extends java.awt.Frame ...
```

That's why you can downcast `AppletViewer` into `Frame`.

> I think, You are mixing `getParent()` method with the `inheritence`. Here `parent` means `the parent container of this component` not component's immediate super-class.

For more info have a look at [Component#getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29).

Comment: How do you trace the hierarchy of these containers? I guess what I'm saying is how do you know those are the parent containers?

Comment: Its so simple. I printed `this.getParent().getClass().getName()` then I printed `this.getParent().getParent().getClass().getName()`.

Comment: Okay, I thought there might be a predefined list. Thanks alot!

Comment: If AppletViewer is a Frame, I don't see why you would need a cast. When I take out the cast, it ends up with the error "cannot convert from Container to Frame".

Comment: `getParent()` is a method of `Component` class that returns super type `Container` that's why you have to downcast it. The best way is use `instanceof` operator in such condition.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help as you have cleared up many problems I didn't know or have overlooked.